# Read output of linux command without using temp file

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I need to read input of some linux commands to a QString variable. At first, I redirect the stream to a temp file and read from it.

However, I don't like this way. I want to avoid access the hard drive, the less the better.

I try to use the environment variable as the "temp file", then use `getenv` to get it into a variable.

like this:

```
QString query="a=$(fdisk -l)";
system(a.toStdString().c_str());
```

...

```
  char* env;
  env= getenv ("a");
```

however, I get nothing. Add `export` to the query has the same result.

I manually check the variables by `env` command. Nothing changed!

So how to fix this? And are there any better way to do this?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

PS: I want to keep the format too, it should keep `\t`, `\n`...

Comment: You might want to read about [`popen`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).

Comment: I suggest you use QProcess, rather than the system command: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html

Comment: Thank both of you for the suggestion, I'm reading about `popen` and `QProcess`. I ain't a lazy ass, but it would be nice if you guys provide some examples :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **Qt** then you should make it in a **Qt's fashion**, by utilizing [`QProcess`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QProcess.html) class.

```
#include <QProcess>

QString command = "/usr/bin/fdisk";
QStringList arguments;
arguments << "-l";

QProcess process;

process.start(command, arguments);

process.waitForFinished(-1);

QByteArray rawOutput = process.readAllStandardOutput();

QStringList output = QString(rawOutput).split("\n");
foreach (QString line, output)
{
    // do something with each line from output
}
```

Comment: Your solution works :) However, my friend suggest me to use `QProcess::write()` instead of `process.start(command, arguments);` : It's will be more convenient to enter a long command with many arguments. Thank :)

Answer (score -1):

It cannot work as you wish, because `system`  or `popen`  will start using `fork` its own shell process, and the `a` variable is not exported, and even if it was, it will be available only in that shell process and not in the invoking original process.

Remember that changes in child processes cannot affect their parent process in general (except by using some explicit IPC such as pipes between the two).

The only way you could do what your want is to use `popen`  (or some QProcess specific mechanism to read on pipe the stdout of the child command) on `fdisk -l`  then (if you absolutely want to have your `getenv` later working) use `putenv` to set your environment variable.

BTW, `fdisk`  is probably using `/proc` to get its information (which you could get directly, see [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) ...).

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), and about [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) and [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

Comment: 'then use putenv to set your environment variable.' I do not think OP wants to set that variable, he tries to use variable to communicate. So I would say that is completely unnecessary when you use popen